# How to find out if the content of two tags correspond?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of .html files. And I want to know if the words of two tags correspond. For example:

```html
<title>I have a dream</title>

<h1 class="cors">I have a dream</h1>
```

This is correct, the same content. But, what if the content of some tags doesn't correspond, like in this case:

```html
<title>I have a dream</title>

<h1 class="cors">My music is the best</h1>
```

How can I find the differences or similarities?

My method is to extract any `<title>` and `<h1>` tags with a simple search from editor, and to use Excel to compare.

But maybe a REGEX will be faster.

Comment: What programming languages are options for you? Do you need to parse an entire document and identify tags that are different, or are you just working with particular tags you can identify easily (like title)?

Comment: is this [`(?s)<.*?>(.*?)<\/.*?>.*?<.*?>\1<\/.*?>`](https://regex101.com/r/awO6XO/1) what you want?

Comment: I am using only notepad++ and html, no other languages except Regex (that helps me a lot)

Comment: Siam, works great for the first case. Your regex finds the similarities. But to be much easier, I need to find those tags that doesn't correspond, like in the 2 case. And I need to use the exactly those tags, not any tag.

Comment: I made now 2 regex expressions: The first selects everything from the <title>, `(<title>)[\s\S]*?(</title>)[\s\S]*?` and the second regex selects everything from the <h1>, like `(<h1)[\s\S]*?(</h1>)[\s\S]*?`

The problem, how to compare those 2 so as to find the differences?

Comment: So, I find a solution, because I am using a regex editor, like GrepWin or TextCrawler.

Search this regex `(<title>)[\s\S]*?(</title>)[\s\S]*?|(<h1)[\s\S]*?(</h1>)[\s\S]*?`

Copy textresults from the content and then compare it.

Comment: how about [`<title>([^<]*)</title>\s*<h1[^>]*>(?!\1)[^>]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/L4AWKV/1/) to find the different ones.

Comment: SUPER ANSWER !! THANK YOU ! How can I accept and rank your answer?

Comment: And one more thing. If I have those two tags at a distance of several lines between them, how can I chance your regex so as to work?

Comment: @RobRob I put the comment as answer. With "distance" you mean such as certain amount of empty lines in between. Eg with up to 3 empty lines in between instead of `\s*` use [`(?:\h*\R){0,4}`](https://regex101.com/r/njA3g1/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the tags with different content [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the content of the first tag and check in the second tag if it does not match what's inside first by use of a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for backreference to `\1`.

```
<title>([^<]*)</title>\s*<h1\b[^>]*>(?!\1)[^>]*>
```

[See demo and more explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L4AWKV/2)

To match any amount of any characters in between use `.*?` instead of `\s*`

```
(?s)<title>([^<]*)</title>.*?<h1\b[^>]*>(?!\1)[^<]*</h1>
```

[See another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tgEuj6/4)

If you need to remove those tags you can use another capturing group, [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgEuj6/5).

Comment: hello. Actually, I am trying to solve another scenario. Between <title> and <h1> there are many lines, with text and other html scripts. I need to compare those tags Without considering other full lines between them. See here:  https://regex101.com/r/tgEuj6/3

Comment: @RobRob Why not make it clear in question what exactly you're going to do. Did an update of answer.

Comment: GREAT ANSWER ! Thank you.